# Delayed job workers takes running job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

My environment: CentOS, Rails 4, Ruby 2.

I'm running in Delayed Job infinite loop that getting in real time information from some another site.

The task is to run simultaniously many processes to get information from different sites. For each new process I add it to DJ queue by running `search_engine.delay.track!`.

So when I run one worker it successfully takes first job from queue and when job complete takes next. When I run more than one worker by `./bin/delayed_job -n5 start` every DJ worker takes first job in queue and starts to `track!` it. But I want them to take only jobs, that was not been taked by other workers.

Comment: Seems Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618099/multiple-delayed-job-processes-starting-same-job

Comment: Thanx. You are right. I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

It was because of `Delayed::Worker.max_run_time = 0`. The DJ thought, that work already done and runs it again.